# My loop isn't filling my matrix with the data I ask

Tags: r

I'm trying to fill a matrix with the results of sum I included in a loop, but every time I run the loop, the matrix is shown filled with 0s instead of the values that should be filling it from the loop. This is the code:

```
cada_aerolinea<-unique(aerolineas)
resultados<-matrix(0, length(cada_aerolinea), 1)
row.names(resultados)<-cada_aerolinea
for (i in length(cada_aerolinea)) {
  resultados[i]<-sum(fatalities[aerolineas==cada_aerolinea[i]])
  print(resultados[i])
}
```

When I run the full code, the line "print(resultados[i])" only gives back one number, "41", which I don't know where it comes from, and when I just run "resultados", r just shows the matrix filled with 0s. Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i in length(cada_aerolinea)) {
```

should be

```
for (i in 1:length(cada_aerolinea)) {
```

I'm doing that mistake all the time ;). Also, I think you can replace your loop by:

```
resutados = tapply(facilities, cada_aerolinea, SUM)
```